# Adding addChild () to arryas actionscript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I need these 2 items in  my array to show up on the stage. For now these are all the items in the array. The question is how do I add these 2 objects to stage using array?

```
for (var b:int = 0; b < csa.length; b++)
{
    addChild(csa[1]);
    addChild(csa[2]);
    csa[1].x = 27;
    csa[1].y = 214;
    csa[2].x = 9;
    csa[2].y = 833;
}
```

currently with this it is giving me this error :

> TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
>       at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
>       at SkoolBook_fla::MainTimeline/frame26()[SkoolBook_fla.MainTimeline::frame26:10]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array index starts from zero, not from one. So when there are two valid items in `csa`, the valid elements are `csa[0]` and `csa[1]`. `csa[2]` is not valid. You need to use 0, 1 instead of 1, 2 as indexes. `addChild` is throwing error when it is called with an undefined element (`csa[2]`).

Just a note not related to the error:- I don't see any reason of using loop when you are accessing two elements directly.

Comment: heeh yah i am still trying to learn about the programming structures :p but these were originally choices that I needed access to..this was the only way I knew. can u tell me the otherway without looping

Comment: You do not need the loop when you are using `csa[0]`, `csa[1]` directly. You are not using loop index `b`. If you use loop then you should use `csa[b]` instead of accessing both elements directly inside the loop.